# How to get mouse pointer location relative to frame

Tags: java, mouse-position

I want to get mouse location relative to the frame.

MouseInfo give me the absolute location.

How to get poisition relative to the frame? tahnks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the absolute location of the frame with getLocationOnScreen(), and then compute the relative distance.

Comment: After I understood that there are no built-in methods that could help this - 
 I did it by myself. but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First, walk up the tree from your current scope to the top (that will be the frame):

```
Container container = this.getParent();
Container previous = container;
while (container != null)
{
    previous = container;
    container = container.getParent();
}
```

previous is the top container

```
if (previous instanceof JFrame)
{
    Point p = ((JFrame)previous).getMousePosition();
    System.out.println(p); // or do what you need to with p
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the location of the mouse **relative to the frame**, you must subtract the **absolute location** of the mouse from the **location of the frame**, thus cancelling the extraneous points from the  upper left corner of the frame to the upper left corner of the screen.

To get location of mouse relative to the frame as a **Point**:

```
public Point getLocationRelativeTo() {
    int x = frame.getX() - MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
    int y = frame.getY() - MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
    return new Point(x, y);
}
```

To get the x as an **int**:

```
public int getXRelativeTo() {
    int x = frame.getX() - MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
    return x;
}
```

To get the y as an **int**:

```
public int getXRelativeTo() {
    int y = frame.getY() - MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
    return y;
}
```

I hope the helped. :)

For more info, visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/MouseInfo.html