# Mouse pos relative to frame java windows is wrong

Tags: java, windows, swing

I have an application that opens a window and calculates the relative pos to frame as showed in there : [How to get mouse pointer location relative to frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700520/how-to-get-mouse-pointer-location-relative-to-frame) . In Linux this works fine, but **when running it on Windows, the Y-Coordinate is around 30px to big**
*(probably the window border height ?)*. Thanks for help.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;


public class Name extends JFrame {
     public Name() {
         super("Name");
         setTitle("Application");
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setSize(400,400);
         setResizable(true);
         setVisible(true);
         int x;
         int y;
         while (true){
              x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x-getX();
              y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y-getY(); //This is around 30px to big in windows
              System.out.println("X : "+Integer.toString(x)+" Y : "+Integer.toString(y));
              try { //Update screen every 33 miliseconds = 25 FPS
              Thread.sleep(33);
              } catch(InterruptedException bug) {
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
              System.out.println(bug);
              }
         }
     }
     public static void main(String args[]){
         new Name();
     }
}
```

This code compiles without any error and works fine, but for me, it seems that **in Windows the Y-Coordinate is around 30px to big.**
Note : This is only a simplified version of the real application, so probably the error wont occur here. But I havent got a Windows device at home, so Im not able to test it.

Comment: Post an [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: How does that code compile? If you want our help then make an effort to post a reasonable question with complete code. (1-)

Comment: I have edited my answer. It compiles and works fine, but as I wrote my problem **isnt** that it doesnt compiles or works, but that the printed Y-Coordinate seems to be wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Component;

public class Name extends JFrame {
     public Name() {
         super("Name");
         setTitle("Application");
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setSize(400,400);
         setResizable(true);
         setContentPane(new Pane());
         setVisible(true);
         int x;
         int y;
         Component[] rel;
         while (true){
              rel = getComponents();
              x=MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x-rel[0].getLocationOnScreen().x;
              y=MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y-rel[0].getLocationOnScreen().y;
              System.out.println("X : "+Integer.toString(x)+" Y : "+Integer.toString(y));
              try { //Update screen every 33 miliseconds = 25 FPS
              Thread.sleep(33);
              } catch(InterruptedException bug) {
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
              System.out.println(bug);
              }
         }
     }
     class Pane extends JPanel {
         public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { //Here is were you can draw your stuff
             g.drawString("Hello World",0,20); //Display text
         }
     }
     public static void main(String args[]){
         new Name();
     }
}
```

this did the trick

Answer (score 0):

The code is calculating the difference between the mouse position and the top left corner of the window, that is, the position relative to the window. I suppose you want the position relative to the top left corner of the internal frame (content pane), so try

```
    ...
    while (true){
        Point reference = getContentPane().getLocationOnScreen();
        x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x-reference.x;
        y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y-reference.y; 
        ...
```

not tested on Linux...

Comment: But I have still a problem:This code doesnt works (in Linux) when I move my window...